# Can I import new list of Accounts & Contacts in Dynamic CRM 2015 and overwrite the existing Accounts & Contacts list?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I am using Dynamic CRM 2015. I would like to know if  I can import a new list of Accounts & Contacts and overwrite the existing Accounts & Contacts list in Dynamic CRM 2015.

There is relational data of Accounts & Contacts in Lead, Opportunity & other Custom entities.

If I can overwrite the existing list of  Accounts & Contacts, then what will happen to the relational data of Accounts & Contacts in Lead, Opportunity & other Custom entities?

Comment: This doesn't seem programming related though?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can setup a bulk delete job based on a certain criteria.  So you could setup a delete job for all account and contacts that were created before today, and then import your list.